# Stopping Postback with jquery-confirm confirm box, can't seem to get return value (webform project)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I am trying to change the confirm boxes in my application to something a bit more stylish.

The jquery-confirm.js add on was very appealing but I am really struggling to get it to work the way I want.

I have a simple link button on the page.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ShowConfirm();" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("StatusId")%>' OnClick="DeleteStatus">
```

On their site this is the recommended implementation, but it doesn't return a value or stop postback.

```
$.confirm({
title: 'Encountered an error!',
content: 'Something went downhill, this may be serious',
type: 'red',
typeAnimated: true,
buttons: {
    tryAgain: {
        text: 'Try again',
        btnClass: 'btn-red',
        action: function(){
        }
    },
    close: function () {
    }
  }
});
```

I understand that I can move my onclick function into this, however it then will not be reusable. I just want to stop postback when the user hits cancel. That way I can call it from anywhere and it will just work.

I tried a few things to no avail here are a few examples.
None of these stop the postback, but thought I should include what I have tried.

```
function ShowConfirm() {            
        var Confirmed = $.confirm({
            title: 'Please Confirm!',
            content: 'Are you sue that you want to delete this record?',
            type: 'red',
            typeAnimated: true,
            buttons: {
                tryAgain: {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    btnClass: 'btn-red',
                    action: function () {
                        this.preventDefault();
                    }
                },
                close: function () {

                }
            }
        });
        return Confirmed;
    }
```

Another one

```
function confirmation() {
        var defer = $.Deferred();
        $.confirm({
            title: 'Please Confirm!',
            content: 'Are you sue that you want to delete this record?',
            type: 'red',
            typeAnimated: true,
            buttons: {
                tryAgain: {
                    text: 'Delete',
                    btnClass: 'btn-red',
                    action: function () {
                        //Do something
                        defer.resolve(true);
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                    //Do Something
                    defer.resolve(false);
                }
            }
        });
        return defer.promise();
    };

    function ShowConfirm() {
        confirmation().then(function (answer) {
            console.log(answer);
            ansbool = (String(answer) == "true");
            if (ansbool) {
                alert("this is obviously " + ansbool);//TRUE
            } else {
                alert("and then there is " + ansbool);//FALSE
            }
        });
    }
```

I also tried the last one with sending a return value, but that doesn't work either.
My onclick server side code always executes.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the way this works?

In near "every" case, using some jQuery.UI dialog, sweetalert and in 99% of cases?

These jQuery and JavaScript add-ins ALL, and in ALL cases have one huge "similar" aspect:

that is the code does not wait, nor block the calling code.

The technical term for this type of code is what we call asynchronous.

In a nut shell, WHEN you call such code, the prompt dialog or whatever WILL display, but the code does NOT halt. The routine you call will 100% RUN though its code, display the dialog or whatever and THEN 100% finish, exit and return the value.

The reason for such code is to NOT freeze up the browser, not damage the re-plot, and display of information.

As a result, about the only two commands in JavaScript that actually halt code is

"alert()", and confirm().

The above two commands will halt code. Thus, your question:

You have a plane jane button, and say some code to delete or perform a damaging option, then we all wired up code like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Server delete prompt" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Really delete this file?');"  />
```

And, as we know, if user hits cancel, then the button code does not run.

However, what about those js add-ins, and fancy dialogs? Well, they do NOT wait.

I don't have your particular js add-in, but since we all use jQuery, then I give an example how to do this with jQuery.UI.

So, we take the above button, and now do this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Server Delete Prompt" 
            ClientIDMode="Static" 
            OnClientClick="return mydeleteprompt(this)"/>
```

Now, in above, we call a routine, and it will "display" our dialog prompt. But remember that rule above: The code FLOWS though, does not halt the calling js code.

So, what we need to do is STILL RETURN false the first time. (and now our cool prompt dialog is displayed.

the way to make this work? Well, in above we pass "this". In this context, "this" is the current button. So, our code now looks like this:

```
        <div id="MyDialog" style="display:none">
            <h4><i>my cool dialog text</i></h4>
            <h4><i>This delete can't be undone</i></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var mydeleteok = false
        function mydeleteprompt(cmdBtn) {
            if (mydeleteok) {
                return true
            }

            myDialog = $("#MyDialog")
            myDialog.dialog({
                title: "Delete the whole server system",
                modal: true,
                appendTo: "form",
                buttons: {
                    ok: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                        mydeleteok= true
                        $(cmdBtn).click()
                    },
                    cancel: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                    }
                }
            })
            return false
        }
```

Note VERY - but super duper close in above. The routine will return false. That means you click on the button, call the js routine, dialog is displayed, AND THEN FALSE is returned.

Now, the dialog is displayed. If you hit ok button, we set our variable = true AND THEN click the button again!!!!

This time, the same routine will run, but we set our "flag" = true, and the code runs, and returns true, and our server side button code will run.

It will look like this:

[image]

So, user click on button, code runs, display dialog, returns "false".

Now, if the user hits "ok", then we run this code:

```
                buttons: {
                    ok: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                        mydeleteok= true
                        $(cmdBtn).click()
                    },
```

So, what happens is we set our flag = true, and then click the button again!!! This time, the button calls our routine, but this time the routine WILL return true, and now our server side code for that button will run.

So, your HUGE issue and problem? Near 100%, if not all JavaScript code these days runs asynchronously. It does NOT WAIT.

So, there are advanced concepts such as "await" and things like JavaScript "promise", but it still DOES NOT solve this issue.

So, the asp.net button click event, and using onclientclick is a great feature, but it tends to break down a bit when you want to use some type of dialog "add-in", since as I stated, NONE of them wait. So, you have to adopt the above concept, set a flag (that flag code ONLY runs on page load - first time.

In fact, one could make the case that after I use the .click() to run that button, I probably should set that flag = false again. However, since that server side button is causing a post-back, then in most cases, our flag will be re-set to false.

## Edit: Example with jquery-confirm.

As noted, I never used that confirm library (there is about 1+ million of them to be found - you should perhaps have provide a link).

Regardless, that dialog works like this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            OnClientClick="return myconfirm(this)"              
            />

        <script>

            var myconfirmok = false
            function myconfirm(btn) {

                if (myconfirmok) {
                    return true
                }

                $.confirm({
                    title: 'Confirm!',
                    content: 'Simple confirm!',
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: function () {
                            myconfirmok = true
                            $(btn).click()
                        },
                        cancel: function () {
                            console.log("user hit cancel")
                            
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false  // routine MUST return false!!!!
            }
```

NOTE very careful in above - we return false on the last line!!!

So, button is clicked , client side code runs, displays dialog, returns false.

Now, user either hits cancel button, or hits confirm. If they hit confirm, we set our flag = true, and then click the button passed again. Now, our routine runs again, and returns true this time, and thus your server side code now runs.

## Edit3: - the issue is use of LinkButton

The issue here is that to use jQuery (or even JavaScript) to CLICK a link button?

You have to use this:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' >
                </asp:TextBox>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDel" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                    onclick="cmdDel_Click"
                    OnClientClick="return myconfirm(this)"                        
                    >delete</asp:LinkButton>

                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>


        <script>

            var myconfirmok = false
            function myconfirm(btn) {

                if (myconfirmok) {
                    return true
                }

                $.confirm({
                    title: 'Confirm!',
                    content: 'Simple confirm!',
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: function () {
                            myconfirmok = true
                            $(btn)[0].click()
                        },
                        cancel: function () {
                            console.log("user hit cancel")
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false  // routine MUST return false!!!!
            }
        </script>
```

So, you have to address the click even with [0].

Of course, I never use a link button - I useally just drop in a standard button, and there not a whole lot of reason to use a Linkbutton. But, the issue was and is use of jQuery.Click - it needs that [0] for the click event to work.

The code behind for my linkbutton click event is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdDel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim cmdDel As LinkButton = sender

    Dim intPKID As Integer = cmdDel.CommandArgument

    Debug.Print("code here to delete row with PK id = " & intPKID)

    ' get current repeater row
    Dim OnerepRow As RepeaterItem = cmdDel.NamingContainer

    Debug.Print("Repeter index row click = " & OnerepRow.ItemIndex)

    ' get hotel name texgt box
    Dim txtHotel As TextBox = OnerepRow.FindControl("TextBox1")
    Debug.Print(txtHotel.Text)


End Sub
```

And when I run it
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this (with some small changes) almost works. I have to click the button a second time to execute the serverside code even though it does re-run the procedure with a true  value the first time.

Comment: First time run  - ALWAYS return false. It is the code that runs in your dialog that sets the flag = true, and then we do the button click again. So, yes, the whole idea is that the routine will always be called two times. First time - it returns false, and dialog is now display. I don't use jquery-confirm. However, since you have jquery, then consider using jQuery.UI as I did as jQuery.UI dialogs are rather nice, and they work well for this. But, whatever code the "ok" button runs in your dialog - you set the flag = true, and then click the button having used "this" to pass that button.

Comment: Note how the code at start checks the flag - and if true, we exit and return true - that allows the server side button code to run. So if flag at start of code runs, and returns true. As I pointed out, the code NEVER halts - it always runs right though the routine and exits, and THEN your dialog is displayed. Other way is to use two buttons, hide the real button, and do a js "click" on the hidden button, but either way the outlined approach tends to work for existing code and swapping out the confirm() dialog for a custom one.

Comment: See my 2nd sample and edit. I show how this can work with your jquery-conform example. Remember, you MUST return false here - that prevents your server button code from running. You then in your dialog code, set the flag = true on confirm button click, and then we click the original button again. this time, when the routine runs, it will return true, and hence server side button code runs. If they hit cancel, then the dialog is dismissed and nothing occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the thorough responses. I still face the same issue though, your new code example yields the same results for me. For troubleshooting I had added some alert boxes check values and make sure the button click was happening. When clicking on OK/delete the procedure does execute the code again as it should and alerts of a true value but server side code is never executed. Click the primary button again and it executed with no pop-up confirm. Strange behavior

Comment: You never have to click anything 2 times. You have to post your updated code. And on first time button click you are returning false, and can dismiss dialog and code does not run? You need to post your new code - can't see your code and can't guess your code. And f12 browser debug show no errors?

Comment: And Yes the outlined code and idea been used for years in production code.

Comment: I am not doubting you in any way. I will update my original post but I am using your procedure exactly as you have it. It doesn't make sense at all. I can put an alert box inside the if statement and it comes up as soon as I click the delete button but no serverside code executes. If I click the button again the record is deleted without the confirm dialog. The only difference is I have a command argument on my button, besides that my code is the same as your sample. No errors on the F12. It is also inside a repeater/table but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: the issue of a repeater and that information probably changes this issue by quite a bit. In fact, I don't think using on-client click will stop the repeater row command event from running - but then again, this would have never worked even with a simple js confirm. So, big elephant in the room. However, if this was not working with js confirm, the server side code probably would have run always - regardless of returning false for that link button. this issue will have to be tested.

Comment: Ok, found the issue - the issue is the link button. I never use those (why??). But regardless, see the above edit - the issue was not the repeater, but in fact the jQuery.Click() event - it does not work for a Linkbutton unless you address the child controls in the LinkButton.

Comment: I am completely impressed with your persistence, well done. [0] for the win, works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks - same right back at you - you came back and kept asking. I just don't use the LinkButton very much. Even in a gridview, listview, or repeater, as the above code snip shows, a plane jane button, or often a button I used (since buton can have runat=server, and you can add/use bootstrap "gyphicons" to put a image in the button text. But, regardless, it should have worked. The Linkbutton was the issue - and jQuery.click() does not work without the [0].  I often drop say a delete button into Gridview, repeater etc. Note the trick to get the current row via naming container.